# Сохранение данных без нажатия кнопки

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Имеется несколько `input` на странице, где пользователь вводит данные о себе.

Как передать данные на сервер, если нет никаких кнопок?

К примеру, если мы заходим в настройки в vk.com, что-то меняем и переходим на другую ссылку, то данные автоматически сохраняются.

Comment: ну например когда фокус уходит с инпута, можно взять данные и чтото с ними сделать, или использовать событие `change`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, использовать событие `change`:

```js
$('input:not(:checkbox), textarea').on('change', function() {
  // отправка на сервер
  console.log(this.name + ' - ' + this.value);
});

$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
  // отправка на сервер
  console.log(this.name + ' - ' + $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя" /><br />
<input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Фамилия" /><br />
<input type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Номер телефона" /><br />
<textarea name="text"></textarea><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" /> Запомнить<br />
<input type="radio" name="mailing" value="1" /> Получать рассылку<br />
<input type="radio" name="mailing" value="0" /> Не получать рассылку<br />
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. У меня есть на странице img который хранит аватар, событие change  с ним не работает.